# How to delete specific tags

Tags: python, lxml

I have the following XML file:

```
<book>
 <bookname child="test">
  <text> Works </text>
  <text> Doesn't work </text>
 </bookname>
</book>
```

This is just a one block, there are more than one `<bookname>` tags. I need to iterate through the whole document and remove specific `<text>` tags. How do I do that?

My approach is to create an `ElementTree` first and then get an `Element` instance using `ElementTree.getroot()`. Then I use `Element.clear()`. Is this approach ok? I had want to use `Element.remove()` but I can't get it to work. Can anyone provide me with a sample syntax.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `parentNode.remove(childNode)`. Something like this:

```
>>> etree.tostring(tree)
'<book> <bookname child="test">  <text> Works </text>  <text> Doesnt work </text>    </bookname></book>'
>>> bookname=tree[0]
>>> text2=bookname[1]
>>> bookname.remove(text2)
>>> etree.tostring(tree)
'<book> <bookname child="test">  <text> Works </text>  </bookname></book>'
>>>
```

Here I take the bookname node and ask it to remove it's second child.

For finding the nodes you want to remove, I'd use [xpath](http://codespeak.net/lxml/xpathxslt.html#xpath)

Comment: How do I compare text in XPath?

Comment: Lxml is wonderfully elegant - I've always loved how pythonic its usage seems to be. This is the answer I came here to give.